Babylonian method for random variable?
It is known that the sequence defined by
$$
x_{n+1} := \tfrac12 \left( x_n + \frac{y}{x_n} \right)
$$
converges to $\sqrt{y}$ where $y>0$.
Now suppose $Y_t$ where $t\in[0,T]$ is a positive random process. Define
$$
X_t = \tfrac12 \left( X_{t^-} + \frac{E_t [Y_T]}{X_{t^-} }\right)
$$
and for simplicity let $X_{0^-} := \sqrt{E_0[Y_T]}$.
Is $X_t$ a valid / well-defined process, and if so how does $X_t$ behave as $t \to T$? Is there some way to quantify the error between $X_T$ and $\sqrt{Y_T}$?
I'm not a probabilist/mathematician, but I hope my question and notation is somewhat clear.

What do you mean by $\mathbb E_t[Y_T]$? Maybe you meant $\mathbb E[Y_t]$ or $\mathbb E[Y_T]$.

@MatteoGori Thanks, I mean $E_t [ Y_T] := E [Y_T | \mathcal{F}_t]$ where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration generated by $Y$.

Where does the randomness of $Y_t$ enter into $X_t$? Or any randomness?

@shabbychef The conditional expectation $E_t [ Y_T]$ is itself a random process, so I'd think $X_t$ is a random process as well?

This method can be equally derived from Newton-Raphson method using the fact $f(x)=x^{2}-y$ then $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\left(\frac{x_{n}^{2}-y}{2x_{n}} \right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n}+\frac{y}{x_{n}} \right)$. So we can re-write $X_{t}=X_{t-}-\frac{1}{2}\left(X_{t-}-\frac{E{t}(Y_{T})}{X_{t-}} \right)$. The convergence depends on the variance of the random variable $Z_{t-}=\left(X_{t-}-\frac{E{t}(Y_{T})}{X_{t-}} \right)$. Since this is a function of $X_{t-}$ we write $f(x)=x-\frac{y}{x}$, now we can use delta method to approximately calculate the $Var(Z_{T})=\left(1+\frac{y}{x^{2}}\right)^{2}Var(X_{t})$. Since in delta method we can write $Var(f(X))=f'(x)^{2}Var(X). $So then when the $Var(X_{t-})=0$, $Var(Z_{T})=0$ we have convergence of the process which implies non-randomness of $X_{t}$ to be applied the method of Babylonians. Do you agree?

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "implies non-randomness of $X_t$". Since $X_t$ is defined in terms of $E_t[ Y_T]$ which is a random process, isn't $X_t$ also random then?

@Frido Yes you are definitely right. My point is that this creates a contradiction such that since there is a non-zero variance the sequence will not converge and but for algorithm to converge to $\sqrt(E_{t}Y_{T})$ the variance should disappear. This was my point.

When you write the algorithm to converge to $\sqrt{E_t [Y_T]}$, I think that should be $\sqrt{E_T [Y_T]} = \sqrt{Y_T}$. Also, I am not following why you wrote $Z_{t^-}$, shouldn't it be $Z_t$?

Sorry for my dirty and typo writing. Yes we investigate if the algorithm converges and approximates $\sqrt(Y_{T})$ and again the point is the variance of $Z_{t}$ if you agree. I wanted to keep subscript of $X_{t-}$ since $Z_{t}$ is a function of $X_{t}$ but we can assign $t$ as well. But again I think delta method applies this process and we can approximate it using  $Var(X_{t})$ and $f'(x)^{2}$.Right?

+1 in any case for the effort, but I have to think about your answer more. I agree that if it's possible to show that $Var(X_T - \sqrt{Y_T}) \neq 0$ then there is no convergence.
